# Find an element by xpath w.r.t to other element

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to find an element by Xpath w.r.t other element's xpath.

In the below HTML Structure:

```
<div id='frmKonyLib_pxwgmctProj'>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <img> ------>node 1
                                </td>
                                <td>

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <ul show = "true"> ---> element is visible
                        <li>
                            <table>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <img> ------>node 2
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <a>text node1</a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                            <ul show = "false">
                                <li>
                                    <table>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <img> ------>node 3
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <a>text node2</a>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                    <ul>

                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div
```

The code that i've written to find node1, textnode1 and textnode2 is:

```
WebElement templateElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='frmKonyLib_pxwgmctProj']/ul/li[1]/ul/li[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/img"));
WebElement formElement = templateElement.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='text node1']"));
WebElement widgetElement = formElement.findElement(By.xpath("/ancestor::table[1]/following-sibling::ul//a[text()='text node2']"));
```

In the above code formElement is found, but an exception is thrown for widgetElement.
Please help me in figuring out the error and code suggestions for the logic.

Below is the exception thrown:

```
'Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:191)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:554)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:268)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.findElement(RemoteWebElement.java:171)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebElement.java:244)
at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:344)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.findElement(RemoteWebElement.java:167)
at com.kony.vizAutomation.px.utils.PXUtils.selectWidgetByID(PXUtils.java:195)
at com.kony.seleniumexample.SelectWidgetInPX.main(SelectWidgetInPX.java:16)
```

'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting your xpath with // will search all descendants from the root of the document. If you want to search only the descendants of the given element, start with a dot: .// . Similarly, starting your xpath with a / will search from the root of the document. To search from the given element, simply remove the /, so

```
ancestor::table[1]/following-sibling::ul//a[text()='text node2']
```

instead of

```
/ancestor::table[1]/following-sibling::ul//a[text()='text node2']
```